# Database error 10005 in PowerBuilder application

Tags: sql-server, powerbuilder

I use PowerBuilder 9.0+ Sql Server 2000 and the pc is connected to a local network via a wireless AP. When the condition of network changes(turning off the wireless AP or disconnecting network connection), in the PB application "Database error 10005" happens. Then I unchecked auto close and auto shrink in the property of the database I used. The error still happens when I disconnect network connection but not when turning off ap. How to avoid this error in this condition? Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You might get a better quality answer if you provided the transaction object's SQLErrText when the error occurs. Sometimes this sheds more light on the problem than just the error number.

Comment: Which connection are you disconnecting? The server's? How are you disconnecting it? Why do you need to turn off the AP or disconnect from the network?

Comment: We also need to see your connection string. Change any sensitive information like password to xxx.

Answer (score 0):

Googling this error code suggests the connection is dead when this message is generated. This could be:

- a bug in PB
- a bug in the SQL Server client software
- a bug in the SQL Server server software
- a **feature** of SQL Server (when you think about it, your client is now coming from a completely different IP address; allowing a different IP to "continue" using an existing connection, with credentials and permissions established, sounds like a security risk)

Here's some comments from a PB perspective. (Hopefully someone better versed in SQL Server can jump in as well.)

**PB Bug** The Google search came up with a lot of pre-PB10 problems reporting this error message; this could imply that it *was* a PB problem, or a DBLib problem (PB10 and later ditched the now obsolete MSS/DBLib interface for newer standards). The version of PB you're using *is* pretty old; you might be fighting bugs that were fixed years ago.

**PB work arounds** If SQL Server (client or server software) is doing this to you (deliberately or accidentally), the most elegant thing you can do is to make **all** your database accesses more resilient, looking for errors like 10005, re-establishing a connection, and trying again. That would make the recovery transparent, but would be a lot of work, I'd imagine. (And if someone had the foresight to encapsulate all your database access in a way that would make this easy, they're a better person than I.)

A more ugly solution would be a menu item that would DISCONNECT and re-CONNECT to the database, and give the users instructions to use this when they switched network environments.

Both of these will force you to consider whether anything specific to the database session is being maintained (e.g. physical table or row locks, as opposed to the logical locking the DataWindow natively uses), since all this will be lost when the session gets killed.

Good luck,

Terry.